# Should you write a wrapper for angular material2 components?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am working on several angular 5 projects and we want to use material design components from https://material.angular.io/.

Is it a good idea to write a wrapper layer in order to encapsulate the material design components?
So instead of writing `<mat-card>...</mat-card>` we would write something like `<my-app-card>...</my-app-card>`.

The primary motivation is to ensure a consistent and easy to change UI in all our projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restyle AM's components by yourself and reuse them in different projects - yes, it's a very good idea. But if it's only about styles encapsulation, you can just give a unique `id` to the wrapper or to one of the AM's components and write styles like `#id angular-material-component { "styles here" }`.

Comment: I do not want to restyle AM's components. I want to make sure that they are used in a consistent way.

For example I could pass a configuration object to  my own card component: 
`<my-app-card [config]="config"></my-app-card>`.
The configuration object could have a title, data to be displayed and card actions.

However I fear that I am losing a lot of flexibility that way and that I cannot anticipate all use cases for my `my-app-card` component.

Comment: @alEX this way you can configure **everything**, and it's a good way, I use it too, but I recommend you to think about this separate components as repeated parts of application, not just AM's components. And if you're fear that you will not anticipate all use cases, I recommend you to start with simple component and expand it with new functionality when it's needed (and don't forget to update all insertions of this component after expansion).